# Path to biblatex-caspervector.bst - how to know if it is built properly?

Tags: biblatex

I refer to @JohnKitchin's answer over [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51053/23726). I had `biblatex-caspervector.bst` installed through TexLive on a Mac but `Org-Ref` doesn't seem able to find it. What can I do about it?

Comment: [Org-Ref](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref) is a citation library for Org-mode in Emacs. [biblatex-caspervector](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-caspervector?lang=en) is a package on CTAN.

Comment: I don't have any tex code yet. @JohnKitchin commented that: "If it is an issue you have to look into Latex installation details for where to to put those style files. If your latex file builds fine though I would probably ignore it." That's why I am here.

Comment: There is no such thing as `biblatex-caspervector.bst`. `biblatex-caspervector` is a `biblatex` style (bundle) and therefore consists of `.bbx`, `.cbx` and `.def` files. See https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-caspervector/tex. Those files need to be present on your machine. Check with `kpsewhich caspervector.bbx` etc.

Comment: I don't know anything about `Org-Ref`/`Org-mode`, but `bibliographystyle` is usually associated with BibTeX bibliographies. `biblatex` works quite differently. Have you read https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/master/org-ref.org#biblatex-users

Comment: I've found the path to `caspervector.bbx`: `kpsewhich caspervector.bbx
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-caspervector/caspervector.bbx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-caspervector` is a `biblatex` style. `biblatex` styles don't come with a `.bst` file, instead they usually consist of a `.bbx` file (for the bibliography style) and a `.cbx` file (for the citation style) and additional files (for example a `.def` for shared definitions, a `.dbx` for the data model, `.lbx` files for localisation, ...). This means that there is no `biblatex-caspervector.bst`.

It seems that you only want the `.bst` file for some settings of `org-ref` for org-mode. The manual available at https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/master/org-ref.org has a specific section for `biblatex` users that you should probably read and follow since `biblatex-caspervector` is a `biblatex` style: https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/master/org-ref.org#biblatex-users